# Merging Two Different Class Objects with and identifier

Tags: c#, linq

I have two different class and there is a relation between them. Car_Model class refers Car class with Car_ID.

To map these two class object to each other, I created relation named class. How can I assign car and modelCar into this class without making iteration? Can Linq solve this problem?

```
public class Car
{
    public int ID;
    public String name;
}


public class Car_Model
{
    public int ID;
    public int Car_ID;
    public String date;

}

public class relation
{
    public Car car;
    public Car_Model carModel;
}
```

I did not use entity framework.

```
List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
List<Car_Model> carModelList = new List<Car_Model>();

Car car = new Car();
car.ID = 1;
car.name = "blabla";
carList.add(car);


Car_Model carModel = new Car_Model();
carModel.ID = 1;
carModel.Car_ID = 1;
carModel.date = "01.01.2013";
carModelList.add(carModel );
```

Comment: I think you'd need to supply some example code of how you are getting your cars and models. Is it you creating one of each? You're using entity framework? You have some enumerations full of em?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is using a `Join`:

```
var query = carList.Join(carModelList,
            car_x => car_x.Id,
            car_model => car_model.Id,
            (person, pet) => new  relation { car = car_x, carModel = car_model });
```

You can find more about it and his overloads [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx).